# Libgdx Box2D wrong sprite position on top of body from a tiledmap object layer

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, sprite, tiled

I'm trying to draw sprites onto bodies i've created from a tiledmap objectlayer.
When i draw sprites onto bodies i've manually created from code it works fine. When i however try to draw sprites onto the body i've created from the tiledmap it doesn't put the sprites onto to the body.
It draws them in the world but in the wrong place, kinda like the projectionmatrix is not set or wrong or something.

I have found one with the same problem on stackexchange he/she describes the same problem and with code example. Sadly there is no replies/solutions. I have the same problem, i do not use the pixel per meter conversion though.

First post on stackoverflow...be gentle.. :)

This is the link:
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/86474/box2d-shape-fixture-position-vs-body-position

Let me provide a screentshot aswell of my problem:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPdVv.png

Code:
Game code:

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input.Keys;
import com.badlogic.gdx.InputAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.InputMultiplexer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TiledMap;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TmxMapLoader;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.renderers.OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.MathUtils;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Body;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.BodyDef.BodyType;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Box2DDebugRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.FixtureDef;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array;
import com.seve.carramps.entities.Car;
import com.seve.carramps.handlers.MapObjectLoad;

public class testLevel implements Screen {

    private World world;
    private Box2DDebugRenderer debugRenderer;
    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private OrthographicCamera camera;

    private final float TIMESTEP = 1 / 60f;
    private final int VELOCITYITERATIONS = 8, POSITIONITERATIONS = 3;

    private Array<Body> pigs;
    private Car car;
    static int userd = 0;
    TiledMap map;
    OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer renderer;


    // The pixels per tile. If your tiles are 16x16, this is set to 16f
    private static float ppt = 32f;

    private Sprite carSprite, wheelSprite, treeSprite;

    private Array<Body> tmpBodies = new Array<Body>();

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        world.step(TIMESTEP, VELOCITYITERATIONS, POSITIONITERATIONS);

        camera.position.set(car.getChassis().getPosition().x, car.getChassis()
                .getPosition().y, 0);
        camera.update();

        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

        batch.begin();

        world.getBodies(tmpBodies);
        for (Body body : tmpBodies) {
            if (body.getUserData() != null
                    && body.getUserData() instanceof Sprite) {
                Sprite sprite = (Sprite) body.getUserData();
                sprite.setPosition(body.getPosition().x - sprite.getWidth() / 2,(body.getPosition().y - sprite.getHeight() / 2));
                sprite.setRotation(body.getAngle() * MathUtils.radiansToDegrees);
                sprite.draw(batch);
            }
        }

        batch.end();

        debugRenderer.render(world, camera.combined);
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {

        setupWorld();

        map = new TmxMapLoader().load("carground.tmx");
        renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map);


        createCar();

        new MapObjectLoad(map, ppt, world, "ground", BodyType.StaticBody, null, null);
        new MapObjectLoad(map, ppt, world, "ramps", BodyType.DynamicBody, null, "ramp");
        new MapObjectLoad(map, ppt, world, "treeWalls", BodyType.DynamicBody, treeSprite, "treeWall");
        new MapObjectLoad(map, ppt, world, "enemies", BodyType.DynamicBody, null, "enemy");

        carSprite = new Sprite(new Texture("car.png"));
        carSprite.setSize(4, 2);
        carSprite
                .setOrigin(carSprite.getWidth() / 2, carSprite.getHeight() / 2);
        car.getChassis().setUserData(carSprite);

        wheelSprite = new Sprite(new Texture("wheel.png"));
        wheelSprite.setSize(0.9f, 0.9f);
        wheelSprite.setOrigin(wheelSprite.getWidth() / 2,
                wheelSprite.getHeight() / 2);
        car.getLeftWheel().setUserData(wheelSprite);
        car.getRightWheel().setUserData(wheelSprite);


        inputProcessor();

    }

    private void createCar() {
        // car
        FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef(), wheelFixtureDef = new FixtureDef();

        fixtureDef.density = 5;
        fixtureDef.friction = .4f;
        fixtureDef.restitution = .3f;

        wheelFixtureDef.density = fixtureDef.density * 1.5f;
        wheelFixtureDef.friction = 50;
        wheelFixtureDef.restitution = .4f;

        car = new Car(world, fixtureDef, wheelFixtureDef, -2.5f, 5, 3.8f, 1.7f);
    }

    private void setupWorld() {
        world = new World(new Vector2(0, -9.81f), true);
        debugRenderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer();
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();

    }

    private void inputProcessor() {
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputMultiplexer(new InputAdapter() {
            @Override
            public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
                switch (keycode) {
                case Keys.ESCAPE:
                    ((Game) Gdx.app.getApplicationListener())
                            .setScreen(new testLevel());
                    break;
                }
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
                camera.zoom += amount / 25f;
                return true;
            }
        }, car));
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        camera.viewportWidth = width / 25;
        camera.viewportHeight = height / 25;
    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {
        dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        world.dispose();
        debugRenderer.dispose();
        carSprite.getTexture().dispose();
    }

}
```

Class to get the bodies from the different objectlayers:

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.Map;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.MapObject;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.MapObjects;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.objects.EllipseMapObject;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.objects.PolygonMapObject;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.objects.PolylineMapObject;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.objects.RectangleMapObject;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.objects.TextureMapObject;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Ellipse;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Body;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.BodyDef;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.ChainShape;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.CircleShape;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.PolygonShape;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Shape;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array;

public class MapObjectLoad {

    // The pixels per tile. If your tiles are 16x16, this is set to 16f
    private static float ppt = 32f;

    public MapObjectLoad(Map map, float pixels, World world, String layer,
            BodyDef.BodyType bodytype, Sprite sprite, String userData) {

        buildShapes(map, pixels, world, layer, bodytype, sprite, userData);

    }

//  public MOL(Map map, float pixels, World world, String layer,
//          BodyDef.BodyType bodytype, String userData) {
//
//      buildShapes(map, pixels, world, layer, bodytype, null , userData);
//
//  }

    public Array<Body> buildShapes(Map map, float pixels, World world,
            String layer, BodyDef.BodyType bodytype, Sprite sprite, String userData) {

        ppt = pixels;
        Body body = null;

        MapObjects objects = map.getLayers().get(layer).getObjects();

        Array<Body> bodies = new Array<Body>();

        for (MapObject object : objects) {

            if (object instanceof TextureMapObject) {
                continue;
            }

            Shape shape;

            if (object instanceof RectangleMapObject) {
                // System.out.println("Rectangle found");
                shape = getRectangle((RectangleMapObject) object);
            } else if (object instanceof PolygonMapObject) {
                // System.out.println("Polygon found");
                shape = getPolygon((PolygonMapObject) object);
            } else if (object instanceof PolylineMapObject) {
                // System.out.println("Polyline found");
                shape = getPolyline((PolylineMapObject) object);
            } else if (object instanceof EllipseMapObject) {
                // System.out.println("Circle found");
                shape = getCircle((EllipseMapObject) object);
            } else {
                continue;
            }

            BodyDef bd = new BodyDef();
            bd.type = bodytype;
//          bd.position.set(0, 0);
            body = world.createBody(bd);
            body.createFixture(shape, 1).setUserData(userData);

//          sprite = new Sprite(new Texture("treeWall.png"));
//          sprite.setSize(.5f, 2);
//          sprite.setOrigin(sprite.getWidth() / 2, sprite.getHeight() / 2);
//          body.setUserData(sprite);

            bodies.add(body);

            shape.dispose();
        }
        return bodies;
    }

    private static PolygonShape getRectangle(RectangleMapObject rectangleObject) {
        Rectangle rectangle = rectangleObject.getRectangle();
        PolygonShape polygon = new PolygonShape();
        Vector2 size = new Vector2(
                (rectangle.x + rectangle.width * 0.5f) / ppt,
                (rectangle.y + rectangle.height * 0.5f) / ppt);
        polygon.setAsBox(rectangle.width * 0.5f / ppt, rectangle.height * 0.5f
                / ppt, size, 0.0f);

        return polygon;
    }

    private static CircleShape getCircle(EllipseMapObject object) {
        Ellipse ellipse = object.getEllipse();
        CircleShape circleShape = new CircleShape();
        circleShape.setRadius((ellipse.width / 2) / ppt);
        // circleShape.setPosition(new Vector2((ellipse.x + (ellipse.width / 2))
        // / ppt, (ellipse.y - (ellipse.height / 2)) / ppt));
        circleShape.setPosition(new Vector2((ellipse.x + (ellipse.width / 2))
                / ppt, ellipse.y / ppt));
        return circleShape;
    }

    private static PolygonShape getPolygon(PolygonMapObject polygonObject) {
        PolygonShape polygon = new PolygonShape();
        float[] vertices = polygonObject.getPolygon().getTransformedVertices();

        float[] worldVertices = new float[vertices.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < vertices.length; ++i) {
            // System.out.println(vertices[i]);
            worldVertices[i] = vertices[i] / ppt;
        }

        polygon.set(worldVertices);
        return polygon;
    }

    private static ChainShape getPolyline(PolylineMapObject polylineObject) {
        float[] vertices = polylineObject.getPolyline()
                .getTransformedVertices();
        Vector2[] worldVertices = new Vector2[vertices.length / 2];

        for (int i = 0; i < vertices.length / 2; ++i) {
            worldVertices[i] = new Vector2();
            worldVertices[i].x = vertices[i * 2] / ppt;
            worldVertices[i].y = vertices[i * 2 + 1] / ppt;
        }

        ChainShape chain = new ChainShape();
        chain.createChain(worldVertices);
        return chain;
    }

}
```

Class to create the car:

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input.Keys;
import com.badlogic.gdx.InputAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Body;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.BodyDef;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.BodyDef.BodyType;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.CircleShape;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.FixtureDef;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.PolygonShape;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.joints.WheelJoint;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.joints.WheelJointDef;

public class Car extends InputAdapter{

    private Body chassis, leftWheel, rightWheel;
    private WheelJoint leftAxis, rightAxis;
    public Body getLeftWheel() {
        return leftWheel;
    }

    public Body getRightWheel() {
        return rightWheel;
    }

    private float motorSpeed = 75;

    public Car(World world, FixtureDef chassisFixtureDef,
            FixtureDef wheelsFixtureDef, float x, float y, float width,
            float height) {
        BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
        bodyDef.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;
        bodyDef.position.set(x, y);

        // CHASSIS
        PolygonShape chassisShape = new PolygonShape();
        // chassisShape.set(new float[] {x1, y1, x2, y2}); //counterclockwise
        // order
        chassisShape.set(new float[] { -width / 2, -height / 2, width / 2,
                -height / 2, width / 2 * .4f, height / 2, -width / 2 * .8f,
                height / 2 * .8f });

        chassisFixtureDef.shape = chassisShape;

        chassis = world.createBody(bodyDef);
        chassis.createFixture(chassisFixtureDef).setUserData("car");;

        // LEFT WHEEL
        CircleShape wheelShape = new CircleShape();
        wheelShape.setRadius(height / 3.5f);

        wheelsFixtureDef.shape = wheelShape;

        leftWheel = world.createBody(bodyDef);
        leftWheel.createFixture(wheelsFixtureDef);

        // RIGHT WHEEL
        rightWheel = world.createBody(bodyDef);
        rightWheel.createFixture(wheelsFixtureDef);

        //left axis;
        WheelJointDef axisDef = new WheelJointDef();
        axisDef.bodyA = chassis;
        axisDef.bodyB = leftWheel;
        axisDef.localAnchorA.set(-width / 2 * 1f + wheelShape.getRadius(), -height / 2 * .7f);
        axisDef.frequencyHz = chassisFixtureDef.density; // = density af chassis (5) så den kan holde chassis
        axisDef.localAxisA.set(Vector2.Y);
//      axisDef.maxMotorTorque = 50;
        axisDef.maxMotorTorque = chassisFixtureDef.density * 50;
        leftAxis = (WheelJoint) world.createJoint(axisDef);

        //right axis
        axisDef.bodyB = rightWheel;
        axisDef.localAnchorA.set(width / 2 * .15f + wheelShape.getRadius(), -height / 2 * .8f);

        rightAxis = (WheelJoint) world.createJoint(axisDef);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
        switch (keycode) {
        case Keys.W:
            System.out.println("test");
            leftAxis.enableMotor(true);
            leftAxis.setMotorSpeed(-motorSpeed);
            break;

        case Keys.S:
            leftAxis.enableMotor(true);
            leftAxis.setMotorSpeed(motorSpeed);

            break;

        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
        switch (keycode) {
        case Keys.W:
        case Keys.S:
            leftAxis.enableMotor(false);

            break;

        }
        return true;
    }

    public Body getChassis() {
        return chassis;
    }

}
```

Comment: You could put your code, I think it may be due to many factors, so we can look at something.

Comment: I've now added my own code, should i add resource like sprites etc?